# What's the best way to approach relation does not exist error?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-storage

I'm getting a ProgrammingError relation does not exist for my site. I recently made changes to Postgres. I'm not even sure what would be the best thing to share to help someone understand the issue. Please let me know if you are familiar with this issue. I have seen a lot of problems with this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Also "I recently made changes to Postgres", do you mean you manually changed the schema? (deleted something perhaps) you shouldn't really do that without using the migrations system.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I used to not use Postgres, I made changes to use Postgres and now I'm getting this issue. I don't know what the exact cause is. Does that make sense?

Comment: "made changes to postgres" - does this mean you changed table definitions directly in Postgres without changing the django models and running a proper migration?

Answer (score 0):

A "relation" is something with columns, most likely a table. You get such an error if you try to use a table (or similar object) in an SQL statement, but it cannot be found.

Possible causes:

- You connected to the wrong database.
- The table name has upper case characters, but you didn't use double quotes around the name, so it got folded to lower case.
- You created the table in a transaction, but the transaction didn't get committed.
- You use the table without specifying the schema, but the schema is not on the `search_path`.
- You don't have the `USAGE` permission on the schema that contains the table.